# how to get product in department

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have table for `Departments`, and one for `Categories` and one for `Products`,
where one department can have multiple categories, and one category belongs to one department,
and many categories can belongs to many products and many products belongs to many categories,

eg:

```
class Department {
   public function categories(){
      return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
   }
}

class Category{
    public function department(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,"product_category");
    }

}
```

my question is , how can I get all the product from one department ?

I want somthing like this:

```
$department = Department::find(1);
$products = $department->products;
```

Comment: 1. Use hasMany for products instead of belongsToMany in category model. 2. Look into hasManyThrough relation for your question solution.

Comment: I can use has many becouse the relation between the product and the category is many to many , but the relation between the department and category is one to many

Comment: so if i understood it correctly department has many category and category has many products right?

Comment: yes but categories has many products and products belongs to many categories , using `product_category` pivote